# cfwheels nested properties issue

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfwheels

I'm trying to get this to work...

I have a five tables that I"m trying to tie together: `properties`, `languages`, `propertyLanguages`, `buildings` and `buildingTranslations`

properties,languages and propertylanguages is a typical many-to-many relationship that I have working. What I'm trying to do next is have the buildings, which are linked to the property and have text fields for each language that will go inside the buildingtranslations.

I've setup the foreign keys for the `propertylanguages`, `buildings` and `buildingtranslations`

I'm just not sure how to setup the model and the controller when creating/updating building records

---

edit

I've managed to create a view in mssql that represents the relationship
[image: view]

hopefully this makes it easier to see the relationships.

I want to create and edit Buildings with the translation fields included (and updated in the database)

The languages are assigned at the property level. The building that is linked to the property through the propertyid uses the languages available (through propertylanguages[where propertyid = building.propertyid]) to determine the buildingTranslations required for the building

Comment: Are you trying to get all of that data in a single call to model('').findAll(...) ?

Comment: well findOne(), but not necessarily, just want it working :) It doesn't seem like I can get it in a single call because I cannot include(subinclude) on an object, but it looks like the SQL statement is pretty far off.

Comment: It looks like your diagram is missing the "property" table.

Comment: the only thing that one provides is the property name, the propertyid the other tables use is in the buildings table

Comment: I'm having trouble grasping the relationship between buildings, buildingtranslations, and PropertyLanguages, particularly the role that PropertyLanguages plays between Buildings and BuildingTranslation.  Could you elaborate on that relationship a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this helps some:

*models/Building.cfc*

```
hasMany(name="BuildingTranslations", foreignKey="yrhBuildingId");
belongsTo(name="Property", foreignKey="yrhPropertyId");
```

*controllers/Buildings.cfc*

```
function new () {
  building = model("Building").new();
  building.yrhPropertyId = params.yrhPropertyId; //assuming this was passed in
  requiredLanguages = model("PropertyLanguages").findAll(where="yhrPropertyId=#building.yhrPropertyId#");
}

function create () {
  building = model("Building").new(params.Building);
  building.save();

  requiredLanguages = model("PropertyLanguages").findAll(where="yhrPropertyId=#building.yhrPropertyId#");
  for (var i = 1; i <= requiredLanguages.recordCount; i++)
  {
    buildingTranslation = model("BuildingTranslation").new();
    buildingTranslation.yrhBuildingId = building.id;
    buildingTranslation.yrhLanguageId = requiredLanguages.yrhLanguageId[i];
    buildingTranslation.langName = params.BuildingTranslations[requiredLanguages.yrhLanguageId[i]];
    buildingTranslation.save();
  }

  redirectTo(action="list");
}
```

Comment: It seems like cfwheels has a hundred examples covering one-to-many and many-to-many relationships, but anytime I step outside of it a little bit I end up spending 10hours on a seemingly simple problem.  I think I'll be using this way of handling relationships as I go on.

Comment: One thing I'm wondering is that if the creation fails in the second part, I need to delete the building,  right?

Comment: Not necessarily; it depends on your situation. For example, you could wrap the second part in a try/catch, and if it failed, simply flash a warning message and redirect them back to the 'edit' action (not shown here obviously), passing the new buildingid along with it.  You could also delete the building.  Whatever makes more sense in your case.

Answer (score 0):

here's the approach I've taken

```
    <cfset viewBuildingNames = model("yrhBuildingNamesView").findAll(where="yrhBuildingId=#params.key#")>   <!--- FIND ALL BUILDING NAMES --->
    <cfset yrhbuilding = model("Yrhbuilding").findByKey(key=params.key)>   <!--- CREATE BUILDING MODEL --->
    <cfset yrhproperty = model("YrhProperty").findByKey(key=yrhbuilding.yrhPropertyId, include="YrhPropertyLanguages")>   <!--- language info through property--->
    <cfset yrhbuilding.yrhproperty = yrhproperty>
    <cfset yrhbuilding.yrhBuildingTranslations = ArrayNew(1)>

    <cfloop query="viewBuildingNames">
        <cfset yrhBuildingTranslation = model("yrhBuildingTranslation").new(yrhBuildingId=#yrhBuildingId#, yrhLanguageId=#yrhLanguageId#, langName=#LANGNAME#)>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(yrhbuilding.yrhBuildingTranslations, yrhBuildingTranslation)>
    </cfloop>
```

it's sort of half cfwheels way. it relies on the view created in the database

once the mode; is created, the updating works, but I don't get an error message on the empty langNames, just an error, Which I can live with.

I'm planning on adding another layer of items residing under the building, that will require the same connection to the propertyLanguages, While it should still work OK I'm getting increasingly queasy about the cfwheels magic taking care of these things. I might be switching to handling complex relationships directly.

Comment: Unless the logic is literally straight out the "cfwheels textbook", I tend to handle the insert/update/delete operations "manually", as you mentioned.  It's just less of a hassle.